# How to export and import an user profile from one Quassel core to another?

Tags: database, export, import, irc, user

I have been using Quassel as my bouncer for IRC for quite a long time now.

We (a group of administrators of a small network) have set up a shared Quassel core with many users on the same core.

But now I would like to export everything related to my user account from the Quassel database on this core, in order to re-import it later in another Quassel core on my own server.

Unfortunately, while a feature for adding users has been implemented into Quassel, *nothing is so far provided for either exporting or deleting an user*. (if feature for deleting one user was available, I could have made a copy of the current database, deleted all the other users leaving only mine, and use this resulting database on my own server, while leaving the first one untouched on the shared server)

Despite extensive research on the Internet on this subject, I've found so far no solution.

I have to precise that the backend database for the core has been migrated from the default SQLite backend to a PosgreSQL backend as the database grew sensibly (over 1,5 GB for now).

However I'd be glad to hear from any working solution (SQLite or PostgreSQL backend, it doesn't really matter) describing a way:

- to **export exclusively the data related to one user profile** and then re-import it in a new Quasselcore database

or

- to **delete an user properly from the database without breaking the others user accounts**.

Comment: for better indexation of the question I wanted to tag it with "quassel" but with less than 300 reputation I'm not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

I just found [this](http://bugs.quassel-irc.org/projects/1/wiki/PostgreSQL) while searching for a similar thing, and I'm going to be trying it out shortly. Will report if it works or not.

Exerpt:

> This article describes how you can use Quassel with the PostgreSQL
>   database. It is written from a FreeBSD point of view, but the process
>   should be very similar for any other system out there.
>
> This appeared in Quassel release 0.5.0.

Comment: Not sure it is what I'm looking for. I mean, migrating the DB wasn't a problem at all (I managed to do it quite easily).
I'm interested in handling data at the user profile level (moving or deleting a specific user of the database)

Maybe I have been a bit misleading with in the last sentence of the question, I'll correct it to be more accurate.